# What does it mean when a folder/class is highlighted in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've searched over the Internet but could not find anything.

I don't know what these highlighted files in Android Studio means:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many reasons for a file/directory being highlighted in yellow as you have mentioned in the questions.

1. Generated files from importing external libraries.
2. Read only files that are not editable.
3. System API files
4. Some files that are generated in in the build process.

Note: Files with VCS are marked as following in Android Studio(default behaviour):

1. Maroon for `Untracked files`.
2. Blue for files with changes to last commit.
3. Red for `conflicts`.
4. Black for no change in file comapred to last commit(or no VCS at all).

For more info on File Status color, visit [THIS LINK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html)

Answer (score 3):

There could be many reasons for that. 
Most Probably version control is enabled in your project and the highlighted files and folders indicate that these files are not uploaded to version control system. You can disable this setting in VCS-> Disable Version Control.
Another reason could be that lint warnings are getting highlighted in the UI. Try changing some UI settings in File-> Settings-> Appearance

Comment: is there anyway to see , the lint warnings ? I don't have version control enabled

Comment: Look for settings in File->Settings->Editor. Color settings can also be changed in File->Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->